# loop through list from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have list from backend. I want to loop through all the elements of this list and hide the button if it has no status 6.

**response**

Returning from the response in the incoming list. It won't always be like this. It can come in 7 elements.

```
policyInstallmentDtoList: Array(1)
 0:
 amount: 291
 currency: "TRY"
 date: "10-02-2022"
 installmentNumber: 1
 status: "3"
```

I'm trying to loop through the list here.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (paymentInfoData?.policyInstallmentDtoList?.forEach((e) => e['status'] !== '6')) {
   setHiddenControlButtonClass('hidden');
 }
}
```

**html**

```
<div className={hiddenControlButtonClass}>
  <AS.Button variant="outlined" onClick={handlePayment}>
    Devam
  </AS.Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

It's a built-in method in JS's array prototype which returns a `boolean` value that represents whether or not at-least a single member in the array answers your condition.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (!paymentInfoData?.policyInstallmentDtoList?.some(e => e.['status'] === '6') {
   setHiddenControlButtonClass('hidden');
 }
}
```

This should work just fine and only set the state once,
which is better for performance.

Comment: When the element with a status 3 comes, the button is also hidden.

Comment: What is the initial value of `hiddenControlButtonClass`?

Comment: Edited the answer. The condition was wrong.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I replaced `some`with `every`.

Comment: `every` is incorrect here. Like the name suggests, it will check if **every** status is '6'.

Comment: The reason my previous version didn't work is because we need to make sure the whole statement is false, not `e.['status'] !== '6'`. That was my initial mistake. Note the placement of the `!`. Hence, it should be good now.

Comment: I did as you said and everything seems fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the `forEach` method in an `if` statement.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  paymentInfoData?.policyInstallmentDtoList?.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.status !== '6') {
      setHiddenControlButtonClass('hidden');
    }
  }
}
```